# Regular sending in Telegram bot does not work correctly

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

In parallel with the usual commands in the bot, I am sending information to each user at the user's time.

**Problem:** the dictionary with user data in the threading_control() function is correct, but in the regular_sending() function (nested function) it is not correct, although the data does not change. That is, when sending, I don't know why, the data in the dictionary is from another user, respectively - the sending goes to the wrong person in the wrong time.

**Code:**

```
def get_user_params(user):
    """Return dict with user's data"""
    params = {'id': user[0],
              'name': user[1],
              'send_time': user[2],
              'city': user[3],
              'news_topic': user[4],
              'quantity_news': user[5],
              'status': user[6]
              }
    return params


@aiocron.crontab('* * * * *')
async def threading_control():
    # Get list of tuple with all users
    all_users = db.get_all_users_info()

    for user in all_users:
        # HERE - DATA RIGHT (CORRECT)
        user_params = get_user_params(user)
        print(user_params)
        if user_params['status'] == 1:
            try:
                user_hours_minutes = user_params['send_time'].split(':')
                hours = user_hours_minutes[0]
                minutes = user_hours_minutes[1]

                @aiocron.crontab(f'{minutes} {hours} * * *')
                async def regular_sending():
                    # HERE - DICT WITH ANOTHER USER'S INFO (NOT CORRECT)
                    print(user_params)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, loop=loop)
```

*If I didn’t describe something well, please clarify, my English is so bad:)*

Comment: `user_params` is defined outside of `regular_sending`. It's value isn't read until the function is executed, not when it's defined.

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The fastest way is to change to `async def regular_sending(user_params=user_params):`.

Comment: Thanks! But, I found more elegant solution - work without nested function, decorator. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your code contains one of the common mistakes [late binding closure](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

Comment: And, solution is only redo the architecture?

Comment: You could try to make code without using variables in closures.